# Background tag not working in aframe

Tags: aframe

I have the following code snippet

```
<a-assets>  
 <img id="garage_pic" src="images/labs/SFOGarage_photosphere.jpg">
</a-assets>

<a-sky id="sfogarage" src="#garage_pic" rotation="0 -130 0" visible="true" 
radius="100"></a-sky>
```

Here in the above code, i am trying to access image inside  tag through
src="#garage_pic". But i am not able to access it. my page background is still blank.

Please suggest a solution for the above.  Thanks

Comment: <a-assets>                                                                                                     <img id="charlo_pic" src="images/labs/CharlotteLab_photosphere1.jpg"</a-assets>                                                                                                                                                                                         <a-sky id="sfogarage" src="#charlo_pic" rotation="0 -130 0" visible="true" radius="100"></a-sky>                                                                   code looks something like this

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: i am trying to access image inside <a-sky> tag

Comment: i have <a-assets> tag, where i am pointing to the image location and later i am trying to access the same in a-sky tag

Comment: Add your code snippets. Then stack users can understand your problem easily.

Comment: <a-assets>
    <img id="garage_pic" src="images/labs/SFOGarage_photosphere.jpg">
</a-assets>

<a-sky id="sfogarage" src="#garage_pic" rotation="0 -130 0" visible="true" radius="100"></a-sky>

Comment: I added it above, but it looks clumsy, i added proper indentation, but its not taking it

Comment: Is the image path correct, or is CORS playing a factor?